# IntelliJ GoPluginにてGAE用のブレークポイントが止まらない

Tags: go, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

初歩的な質問となります。

IntelliJにGoPluginを入れてGoogleAppEngine用のコードのデバッグを行おうとしています。
GoogleAppEngineのクイックスタートにあるHelloworldを用いてブレークポイントを止めようとしているのですが該当コードが実行されてもブレークが止まってくれません。

環境は以下となります
OS:Windows10 64bit
IntelliJ:2017.1
GoogleAppEngineSDK:1.9.48
GoSDK:GoogleAppEngineSDK内蔵の物(GoSDK単独のものを使っても結果は同じでした。)
GoogleCloudSDK:141.0.0
GoLangPlugin:0.171.1931
python:2.7.13

IntelliJの設定
Plugin:Go lang plluginのみ
GoProjectを作成し、Run>EditConfigrationでGoAppEngineのconfigを作成し
hostにはlocalhostをしてportはデフォルト(8080)のままです。

helloworldの実行自体はできておりlocalhost:8080にアクセスするとhelloworldが表示されます。

古めの参考ページを見るとdelveが必要というサイトもありましたが、
最近の情報を見るとGo plugin側に組み込まれているという情報もあり、現状delveは入れておりません。

---

追記：
2017/6月現在
IntelliJ go pluginの後継となるgoglandの方でもデバッグはサポートされていないとのことでした。
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-1897